# Multi-start and Multi-end shortest path set

Tags: algorithm, optimization, computer-science, dijkstra, shortest-path

I am having problem with shortest path in directed weighted graph. I know `Dijkstra`, `BFS`, `DFS`. However, I have `a set of vertices S` for starting points and `a set of vertices E to end`. S and E doesn't overlap. So how can I find the set of edges with minimal sum of edge weight? The edge set doesn't have to include all vertices in S, but have to `reach all vertices in E`. Should I start with Dijkstra on all permutation of {Si, Ei} and optimize or I miss any important algorithm I should know? Or even I am over-thinking....

Comment: Add two vertices, a Start, connected to all vertices in S, and End, all vertices in E being connected to. Run Dijkstra on a new graph.

Comment: however, the shortest path (set) will reach End, but not necessarily reach all vertices in E.

Comment: If the path is shortest from Start to End, it is the shortest among all paths from {S} to {E}. Unless I totally misread the question.

Comment: Assuming there are E1 and E2 in set E. You may reach End via E1 and totally miss E2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find the tree of minimal weight in the graph that contains all the vertices of E and at least one vertex from S.

The problem is called [general Steiner tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem#Generalization_of_minimum_Steiner_tree), and it is NP-hard. So the best you can probably hope for is an exponential-time algorithm or some kind of approximation (the [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) of the whole graph comes to mind, maybe after removing some unneeded subtrees).

There is a simple DP solution that works in O(2^n * (n + m)): Let f(S) be the cost of the minimum tree in the graph that spans all the nodes in S. It can be shown that there is such a tree T such that the weight of T \ {x} is f(S \ {x}) for some *x*, so the transition can be done in O(n + m).

Comment: @user1505108 Well then, it's not really obvious, but the problem is hard.

Comment: @user1505108 I added an O(2^n * (n + m)) DP algorithm, if that's helpful. At least it doesn't depend exponentially on the number of edges.